# Vaadin Charts: firing click event with hovered point

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-charts

I have a Vaadin chart like this:

[image: chart with hovered point]
.

My goal is to get the hovered X value when clicking on the chart. Based on the previous image, I would like to get what month area is being clicked (the selected area is blue coloured in the image).

I've added a PointClickListener to that chart and inside that event I can get the needed information, but I have to click exactly hover the point. Clicking in the month area is not fired the PointClickListener:

```
chart.addPointClickListener(
        pointClickEvent -> {
          //Here I get the selected month:
          int monthIndex = event.getPointIndex();
```

So I would like to know if there's any method to obtain the hovered month by only clicking in that area, not exactly above the point.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Chart click event, and you will get the coordinates of the click, the event has info of the coordinates, for your purpose you could use the [xAxisValue](https://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin/vaadin-charts/4.0.5/com/vaadin/addon/charts/ChartClickEvent.html#getxAxisValue--) to know which point is in the clicked zone.

Comment: Is the first xAxis value interval allways [-0.5, 0.5) and it's incremented by 1 in the following values? 

For example, the second month of the serie would have the xAxis value interval [0.5, 1.5), the third [1.5, 2.5)...